# Passing a Streamwriter as a parameter

Tags: c#, parameters

I have a large file and I am reading each line and depending on what the line contains, I am massaging the line.  Here is the code I use when I get to a line that needs to be massaged:

```
    private static void ReviewFile(string fileName, string outFile)
       // next initialize StreamReader and read the first line
       // depending on the value of that line:
       checkFile(out line, ref sw, ref sr);  <--- error
```

Calling:

```
       private void checkFile(out string line, ref StreamWriter sw, ref StreamReader sr)
       { 
         string mVar = line.Trim();  <--- error
         sw.WriteLine(mVar);
         line = sr.ReadLine();
       }
```

It seems like it should work but I am getting multiple errors.  When I call the method, I get "An object reference is required for non-static field"  Then within the checkFile method, I get use of unassigned out parameter line. What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be graciously appreciated.

Comment: What is the premise of this code supposed to do?

Comment: `out line` means you promise to assign something to `line` before returning from the method.  Instead, you're trying to *use* `line` without assigning to it.

Comment: 1) like variables, `out` parameters need to be initialized before they are are used. 2) you almost never need to use `ref`, so you've probably misunderstood its purpose.

Comment: @p.s.w.g is right; there is no need to pass `sw` and `sr` by reference unless you intend, within `checkFile`, to assign new values to them that you want to be reflected in the calling code.

Comment: Please show more context around checkFile. Is this declared in a static method? What are you actually trying to do? Why do you think you need to use "out" and "ref" here?

Comment: cont... 3) `ReadLine` doesn't take any arguments; it returns a string. 4) it looks like `sw` and `sr` are instance fields that you are trying to use within a static method.

Comment: Yes - it is static.  I am using a Streamreader to read in the entire file line by line then using the Streamwriter to write it.  I have to massage some sections and, depending on the section, a different method is called.  If I try to make the sr and sw calls, they are out of scope in the method.

Comment: @Missy You can't "directly" call an instance method from a static method. You can only call instance methods on an actual instance of the object (see also my answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you show, there's absolutely no reason to use `ref` or `out` here.

Also, to directly address the issues you ask about, see my comments:

```
private static void ReviewFile(string fileName, string outFile)
   // You're trying to call an instance method from a static method, which doesn't make sense.
   // Also, where do you actually declare line, sw, or sr? These are, in fact,
   // declared somewhere in this method, right?
   checkFile(out line, ref sw, ref sr);  <--- error
}

// This is an instance method, NOT a static one
private void checkFile(out string line, ref StreamWriter sw, ref StreamReader sr)
   {
      // "out" means you intend to initialize "line" in this method before you use it, and you don't. 
     string mVar = line.Trim();  <--- error
     sw.WriteLine(mVar);
     // ReadLine doesn't take any arguments
     // This should actually be line = sr.ReadLine()
     // Also, this should probably go at the beginning of the method
     sr.ReadLine(line);
   }
```

Comment: I agree with you, no reason for an `out` or `ref`.

Comment: @Greg Yeah, based on the code sample shown in the question, it does seem a little pointless (unless there's something else not shown in the code sample that would justify their use).

Comment: Yeah, up to the OP to edit the question though.

Comment: I edited the posting and +1'ed everyone.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could simply do the following:

```
private IEnumerable<string> ReadByLine()
{
     string line;
     using(StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(FileInformation.FullName))
          while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
               yield return line;
}
```

This would allow you to read the file, line by line.  Then simply pass the data to another method, to sanitize?

```
private void Sanitize(IEnumerable<string> document)
{
     foreach(var line in document)
     {
          // Do you check, to sanitize and return or whatever.
     }
}
```

Then you would simply have a two line call in a method:

```
IEnumerable<string> document = ReadByLine();
Sanitize(document);
```

This approach would separate the functionality a bit, plus will be easier to follow.  Alternative approach to solve your problem.  Especially since you approach doesn't seem warranted or viable to enhance the code in anyway.